# Entity Framework auto assign FK to reference Entity during insertion?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, function

Could you please explain for me Why and How EF auto assign FK to reference entity when i insert entities into Database? I got these simple Entities like this:

First one is Catalogue

```
public class Catalogue
{
    public int CatalogueId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

Second one is Page which reference to Catalogue.

```
public class Page
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CatalogueId { get; set; }
    public Catalogue Catalogue { get; set; }

}
```

The relationship in this case is one to many. So in the code i am using this:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var catalogue = new Catalogue
            {
                Name = "catalogue 1"
            };
            var page = new Page
            {
                Name = "page 1",
                CatalogueId = 0
            };

            context.Catalogues.Add(catalogue);
            context.Pages.Add(page);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The **MyDbContext** is simple nothing special.
When i run this code i am expecting it will generate an error because **CatalogueId = 0** is not valid, **but it working fine,**.

It is interesting me and hopefully someone can clarify that :).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is how EF work under the hood. The context will go and execute the INSERT and generate the update for the FK value in the table. Later, will populate the tracked entity with the real key value.

You can experiment with unattached entities and will notice that no FK value is updated.

Comment: I would like to clarify some point from your answer, _The context will go and execute the INSERT and generate the update for the FK value in the table_ , I think it should be execute two INSERT one for Catalogue entity as normal and one for Page with an action as re-assignment the CatalogueId of Page equal with @@Identity of Catalogue which we just insert in previous command. Otherwise SQL will complaint because when we insert the Page entity with Catalogueid = 0 is not suitable FK cause it was not existing. Could you please give me the correct path? Thank you.

Comment: You can see the exact action using SQL profiler. Your comment sounds reasonable but you can also turn off the restriction, do the insertion, do the update and restore the restrictions back. This will validate the past operations and will roll back the transaction in case of a violation.